# PhpStorm: how to generate constructor with all parent properties and child too

Tags: php, phpstorm

There are few classes:

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    protected Service1 $service1;

    public function __construct(Serivice1 $s)
    {
        $this->service1 = $s;
    }
}

class Child extends AbstractBase
{
    private Service2 $service2;
}
```

If I press `Alt + Insert` (for child class) and select `Constructor`, PhpStorm will show me only properties from child class. How to generate constructor with both: child and parent class, like this?

```
public function __construct(Service1 $service1, Service2 $service2)
{
    parent::__construct($service1);
    $this->service2 = $service2;
}
```

Comment: The best I can suggest right now is this: in `Alt+Insert` menu use `Override Methods...` option instead, there choose `__construct()`. It will create the same method as parent class. You can then move caret to `private Service2 $service2;`, place it on `$service2`, invoke `Alt+Enter` menu and choose `Add constructor parameters` entry.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you a lot. But, i don't know why, phpstorm will add full namespace as parameter type

Comment: Could be your import settings... (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import`) or maybe Code Style. In any case: you can place caret on FQN, invoke `Alt+Enter` and choose "Import" or "Simplify FQN" or alike entry. **EDIT:** Or maybe it's this one? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-53591

Comment: As for the initial issue / question: here is the ticket that seems relevant: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40676

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to generate constructor with both: child and parent class

Currently it's not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40676 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

The best I can suggest right now is this:

- In `Code | Generate...` menu (<kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> on Windows keymap) use `Override Methods...` option instead.
- Then choose `__construct()`. It will create the same method as parent class has.
- You can then move caret to the `private Service2 $service2;` line, place it on `$service2`, invoke <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> menu and then choose `Add constructor parameters` entry.